# making jquery accordions default to closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

You can do `$('#itename').accordion('activate', 0)` to make an accordion closed but that'll change the page focus, which I don't want to do. I could refocus the page to the top but that won't work if I'm doing `whatever.html#elementID` to set the focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `collapsible` to `true`, and `active` to `false`.

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/z7Rhn/

Read More: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible

Answer (score 1):

may be this approach will be useful

write a function to accordion **change**  whcich will do two things:-
1.close the accordion.
2.than write code to focus the new element

change event

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {

});
```